# Using Apache Camel, convert from XMLGregorianCalendar to ZonedDateTime

Tags: apache-camel, converters, zoneddatetime, xmlgregoriancalendar

Using Apache Camel, I'm trying to convert, during a Spring/XML DSL  operation, from an inbound XMLGregorianCalender to a ZonedDateTime.  I created an @Converter method to do this but it never gets called.  How do I get this to work in Apache Camel?  Does anyone have an example?

Comment: Have you checked the docs https://camel.apache.org/manual/latest/type-converter.html

Answer (score -1):

After looking deeper (and reading above) it appears to me that the conversion from XMLGregorianCalendar to ZonedDateTime is successful in my POJO but when marshaled and converted to a string, the JSON representation of this ZonedDateTime object is output as epoch time format.  When I place the JsonFormat annotation on the field for a different format, Camel appears to ignore it.  The documentation says "use the latest version of camel-jackson but my CXF server won't come up with the latest version.  Any hints?

Comment: Please consider editing your question instead of using Answer. You may use answer if you find the answer to your question yourself.